# Find sum of one value from object

Tags: vue.js, sum

I am trying to add values of totale and find their sum, to display in view, but somehow it is not working.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      invoices: [],
    }
  },

  computed:{
    sum () {
      return invoices.map(function(invoice) {
        return invoice.sum.map((inv) => inv.totale).reduce(function (total, inv) {
          return total + inv
        }, 0);
      });
    }
  },
}
```

image of data:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNd1D.png)

Comment: What does it mean "somehow not working"? You have an error? What is it? Or sum does not match? What's wrong?

Comment: Well for one you need `this.invoices`

Comment: What I can see from the image you've shared - there is no `sum` property in the object in the list! You're using `map` on something that's missing :)

Comment: This should give you a proper error message in your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      invoices: [{ totale: 10 }, { totale: 10 }, { totale: 10 }],
    }
  },

  computed: {
    sum() {
      return this.invoices.reduce((acc, { totale }) => acc + totale, 0);
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">{{ sum }}</div>
```